# deploy or pull glue job from Github repo

Tags: aws-glue

We have a github repo for glue jobs. All our jobs are pushed to development branch
Now we have set up stage environment (new AWS account We are using different organisational unit for each environment.) to deploy these glue jobs from git. When i am trying to pull the glue job from git it is throwing this error

**Pull from repository
Unable to pull job jb_common_utilities from GitHub at cosx/development. Unable to convert from `String` to `Job` model..**

Need help to understand the above issue.

Also what is the best way to deploy glue jobs and lambda function from dev environment to other environment.

Need help to understand the above issue.

Also what is the best way to deploy glue jobs and lambda function from dev environment to other environment like stage or prod.